# I want to print last month last date with time stamp '23:59:59' using command

Tags: linux, datetime-format, date-manipulation

Below is my output but I want to get output like `Apr 30 23:59:59`. 
Please suggest

```
date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day"
```

Output:
`Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 UCT 2019`

I want output: `Tue Apr 30 23:59:59 UCT 2019`

Comment: Does changing `-1 day` to `-1 second` give your desired output?

Comment: yes i got it thank you very much @barbsan

Comment: i want to print like 20190430 (lastd ay of previous month it can be 28 or 30 or 31)

Comment: If you type `date --help` you'll see manual, scroll to section **FORMAT** (Note that you have to use in command *your date command* `+"` *desired format* `"`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass another +format to date and replace the time with the 23:59:59. Something like this:

```
date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day" +"%a %b %d 23:59:59 %Z %Y"
```

And the output will be:

```
Tue Apr 30 23:59:59 -03 2019
```

Update: to have the last day of the previous month using the format YYYYMMDD, just change the last format string to `'%Y%m%d'`. Here is the full command:

```
date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -1 day" +"%Y%m%d"
```

And here is the output:

```
20190430
```

Comment: i want to print like 20190430 (lastd ay of previous month it can be  28 or 30 or 31)

Comment: Just change the last format string to +'%Y%m%d' so.